# Very high system load on Ubuntu 22.04, probably related to mounting Samba/CIFS shares and kernel 6.5.0-15, why? Problems started in January 2024

Tags: 22.04, samba, cifs, cpu-load

**The short version:** I have a very high system load (load is 17 with 4 CPUs), and cannot pinpoint the reason, on a 22.04.3 system with kernel 6.5.0-15-generic. But it appears to be related to the number of currently mounted Samba/CIFS shares from other devices on my LAN. I'd really like some troubleshooting help here, or a workaround if this is a known issue that I haven't been able to find by googling.
**I can't find the bottleneck, no system monitoring tool or dmesg/journalctl output shows me any sign of why the load is that high. Any ideas?**

**More background and longer version:** I have a couple of Ubuntu systems, from a desktop to Raspberry Pis and other single-board computers, running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS or 20.04 LTS. I have not touched any configuration that I suspect can be related for several months, but I recently (in January 2024) noticed a ridiculously high system load without any obvious cause on one of them. Problem persisted after reboot. (These systems all run `unattended-upgrades`, so they are more or less up-to-date, but it often goes weeks between reboots so the kernel version might be different.)

I also noticed a very high utilization (> 16) on my desktop (8-core/16-thread AMD CPU) once after a Samba share crashed, but that problem did go away after a reboot, haven't been able to reproduce it.

**System info (where I did reproduce the error):** Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, 4 cores, Intel Celeron J4105, 8 GB RAM. `uname -a`: 6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jan 12 18:54:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Tests and test results:** I stopped all high-CPU or disk-intensive processes, and tested different number of mounted Samba shares. In all cases, `iostat` reported `avg-cpu %idle` to be > 97 (if I didn't run `iotop`, which when I did increased `%system` to 2-3 and reduced `%idle` to about 90). `iostat` also reported disk `%util` < 1 and practically zero transactions per second, and `iotop` didn't show anything either, so the load does not seem to be disk-related. `htop` showed no process (except `iotop`) to use > 5% CPU.
The Samba shares were mounted, but not used: `lsof` did not list any files under `/media` or `/mnt` (where these mountpoints are).

To me, the load average should be very close to zero here. But it isn't.

- Zero (0) Samba shares mounted: Load was about 0.2. So practically zero.
- Two (2) Samba shares mounted, one share per external Ubuntu system on my LAN: Load was about 4.
- Four (4) Samba shares mounted, to two separate systems on my LAN: Load was about 8.
- Ten (10) Samba shares mounted, to five different systems both on LAN and via VPN: Load was about 17.

**Counterexample 1:** A Raspberry Pi 4, running Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS (i.e., not 22.04) with `uname -a` showing "5.4.0-1100-raspi #112-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 24 15:35:17 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux" and 20 active Samba shares mounted had a load of about 0.2. Again, practically zero.

**Counterexample 2:** My desktop, running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (same as system above, but an AMD CPU) with `uname -a` showing "6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 10:53:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux" and 16 active Samba shares mounted had a load of about 0.3. Again, practically zero.

**Note:** I just noticed that I don't have the same kernel version on both x86_64 systems. But looking in /boot, both of them got 6.5.0-15 installed on the 12th of January. So I guess I could reboot my desktop and select the 6.5.0-15 kernel, and see if the problem appears on the desktop too.

**Other things I've tested:** By googling, some people seemingly got better Samba performance by adding "vers=3.0" to the `cifs` lines in `/etc/fstab`. I tried both with and without, but did not see any difference. A reboot did not help.

**Suggestions on the way forward are welcome...**

**Edit:** I did reboot my desktop and chose the 6.5.0-15-generic kernel in Grub (`uname -a`: "6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jan 12 18:54:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"), and had 16 Samba shares mounted: The system load jumped up to 27 - But the system seems as responsive as ever.

**My conclusion is that the 6.5.0-15-generic kernel reports the load incorrectly when Samba shares are mounted.**

But what is the next step? How to mitigate it, except pinning the older kernel? And where to report the bug?

Comment: I could add that the system doesn't "feel" as sluggish as a load of 17 would imply, but it is a headless box that primarily handles backups and acts as a Wifi AP, not many resources required.

I guess it is possible that there is a bug that reports a too high load value, but the system might not be that stressed after all... I'd still like to get to the root cause.

Comment: Perhaps/perhaps not relevant in this context: The 6.5.0-15 kernel (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/6.5.0-15.15) did actually include a fix for CVE-2023-6606 (https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-6606) that involves Samba/CIFS, but not in a way that (as far as I can see) should be related to system load calculations (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218218).

Comment: There is a similar thread over on [Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494428). For my part of it, I went down another rat hole and haven't gone back to it for a week.

Comment: Have you checked which processes are using what percentage of the CPU? It would be unlikely that the kernel is reporting such a high load without _something_ burning cycles (though 17 for 4 CPUs sounds impossible - it's supposed to be 1 for a fully loaded CPU, right?) I would take a look with `htop` and in settings hide the userland threads and unhide the kernel threads. Something should show up?

Comment: @zwets: I mentioned that no processes consume more than a few percent, except iotop (which I didn't run very often during these tests). And the total, accumulated CPU load was probably less than 10%. As checked using htop. htop/iostat/etc confirmed that the disk utilization and cpu load (including %iowait) was practically zero, and I could not find another source for the high load. I think the load value is incorrect.

Comment: @DougSmythies: Thanks, seems I'm not the only one. The bug report mentioned in that thread (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-6.5/+bug/2049242) concerned 6.5.0-14, not -15, but close enough. (Something mentioned there was upgrading to a mainline kernel, but I don't have the time to tinker with that since I'm not the only one using that system.)

Comment: Further evidence that the load is incorrectly reported: I played "supertuxcart" (from snap) for a while, and it was very responsive, despite htop showing a load of about 27 before and after playing. (I did not have a more official performance benchmark tool available, and even if I had, I don't have old data to compare it with.) The most annoying effect I've seen so far is that my system monitoring using Nagios shows a big, red "CRITICAL" problem due to high load.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the root cause, but now after a couple of weeks, the kernel has been upgraded to `6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu`, and the load is reasonable once more. I have not made any configuration changes since the above comments.

I can only assume that there was a kernel bug from or before 6.5.0-15, that was fixed prior to the 6.5.0-26 release.